# Vertically center align icon inside floating element

Tags: html, css

I have found so many answers about this problem here and tried them out on this with no luck.

How to set vertical alignment of all three icons to center/middle?

Here is the:  [Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9p2fd0kL/)

```css
.fl{float:left} 
.fr{float:right} 
.vm{vertical-align:middle}
.ico {display:inline-block;width:16px; height:16px; line-height:16px; 
      background :url('http://files.fbstatic.com/PostImages/2664562/0/b0617e92-af51-4ca9-9b2f-3225c7607441.png') 0 0 no-repeat}
.icoHome{background-position:-48px -160px}
.icoHome:hover{background-position:-48px -176px}
.icoPrev{background-position:-384px 0px}
.icoPrev:hover{background-position:-384px -16px}
.icoNext{background-position:-400px 0px}
.icoNext:hover{background-position:-400px -16px}
.CTitle  {border-bottom:1px #e5e5e5 dashed; height:26px; line-height:27px; background-color:#FFFFDF;padding:2px;}

.BNav, .BNav2{line-height: 24px; display: block; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: navy; background-color: #CCFFFF; width: 90px;
   height: 24px; text-align: center; border-radius: 20px; text-decoration: none;}
.BNav:hover, .BNav2:hover{color: green; background-color: lime}
.BNav2 {padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; width:80px} 
.BNav2:hover .icoHome{background-position:-48px -176px}
.BNav2:hover .icoMenu{background-position:-112px -16px} 
.BNav2:hover .icoDel{background-position:-368px -16px}
.BNav2:hover .icoMove{background-position:-384px -48px}
.BNav2:hover .icoPrev{background-position:-384px -16px}
.BNav2:hover .icoNext{background-position:-400px -16px}
.BNav2:hover .icoLink{background-position:-400px -48px}
```

```html
<div class="CTitle" style="clear:both; overflow:hidden">
  <a class="BNav2 fl" title="Home" href="../A.html">      <!-- float:Left -->
    <span class="ico icoHome fl vm"></span> <!--float:left, problem : how to align middle vertically-->
    Test
  </a>
  <a class="BNav2 fl" title="Previous" href="../B.html">  <!-- float:left -->
    <span class="ico icoPrev fl vm"></span> <!--float:left, problem : how to align middle vertically-->
    Previous
  </a>
  <a class="BNav2 fr" title="Next" href="../C.html">      <!-- float:right -->
    <span class="ico icoNext fl vm"></span> <!--float:left, problem : how to align middle vertically-->
    Next
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've had the most luck using the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Comment: Also this can be done with `flex`, [see a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9p2fd0kL/6/).

Comment: Thank you very much. {flex} is the best possible answer so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to use flexbox.  It's designed for problems just like this one.  Flexbox is nice because it will work to center your icons even if you change the height.  No calculations necessary.  It even works when you use a fluid height.  Here's a nice [cheat sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by Chris Coyier at css-tricks with more of the options flexbox has.  Just in case here's the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

All you need to do is put `display: flex` and `align-items: center` in your css rule for `.BNav2`.  Flexbox does the rest!

```css
body {
  color: #666;
  font: 12px/20px'Open Sans', arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #CCD9C8;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

body.page {
  color: #bbb;
}

.fl {
  float: left
}

.fr {
  float: right
}

.vm {
  vertical-align: middle
}

.ico {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  background: url('http://files.fbstatic.com/PostImages/2664562/0/b0617e92-af51-4ca9-9b2f-3225c7607441.png') 0 0 no-repeat
}

.icoHome {
  background-position: -48px -160px
}

.icoHome:hover {
  background-position: -48px -176px
}

.icoPrev {
  background-position: -384px 0px
}

.icoPrev:hover {
  background-position: -384px -16px
}

.icoNext {
  background-position: -400px 0px
}

.icoNext:hover {
  background-position: -400px -16px
}

.CTitle {
  border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 dashed;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 27px;
  background-color: #FFFFDF;
  padding: 2px;
}

.BNav,
.BNav2 {
  line-height: 24px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: navy;
  background-color: #CCFFFF;
  width: 90px;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.BNav:hover,
.BNav2:hover {
  color: green;
  background-color: lime
}

.BNav2 {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.BNav2:hover .icoHome {
  background-position: -48px -176px
}

.BNav2:hover .icoPrev {
  background-position: -384px -16px
}

.BNav2:hover .icoNext {
  background-position: -400px -16px
}
```

```html
<div class="CTitle" style="clear:both; overflow:hidden">
  <a class="BNav2 fl" title="Home" href="../A.html">
    <span class="ico icoHome fl vm"></span> Test
  </a>
  <a class="BNav2 fl" title="Previous" href="../B.html">
    <span class="ico icoPrev fl vm"></span> Previous
  </a>
  <a class="BNav2 fr" title="Next" href="../C.html">
    <span class="ico icoNext fl vm"></span> Next
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use **fixed height** on both the container and the icon, so you can just to set some `margin` to it. The container's height is `24px` and icon is `16px` - `(24-16)/2=4`.

```
.ico {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9p2fd0kL/7/

```css
.ico {margin-top:4px;} /*ADDED*/

.fl{float:left} 
.fr{float:right} 
.vm{vertical-align:middle}
.ico {display:inline-block;width:16px; height:16px; line-height:16px; 
      background :url('http://files.fbstatic.com/PostImages/2664562/0/b0617e92-af51-4ca9-9b2f-3225c7607441.png') 0 0 no-repeat}
.icoHome{background-position:-48px -160px}
.icoHome:hover{background-position:-48px -176px}
.icoPrev{background-position:-384px 0px}
.icoPrev:hover{background-position:-384px -16px}
.icoNext{background-position:-400px 0px}
.icoNext:hover{background-position:-400px -16px}
.CTitle  {border-bottom:1px #e5e5e5 dashed; height:26px; line-height:27px; background-color:#FFFFDF;padding:2px;}

.BNav, .BNav2{line-height: 24px; display: block; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: navy; background-color: #CCFFFF; width: 90px;
   height: 24px; text-align: center; border-radius: 20px; text-decoration: none;}
.BNav:hover, .BNav2:hover{color: green; background-color: lime}
.BNav2 {padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; width:80px} 
.BNav2:hover .icoHome{background-position:-48px -176px}
.BNav2:hover .icoMenu{background-position:-112px -16px} 
.BNav2:hover .icoDel{background-position:-368px -16px}
.BNav2:hover .icoMove{background-position:-384px -48px}
.BNav2:hover .icoPrev{background-position:-384px -16px}
.BNav2:hover .icoNext{background-position:-400px -16px}
.BNav2:hover .icoLink{background-position:-400px -48px}
```

```html
<div class="CTitle" style="clear:both; overflow:hidden">
  <a class="BNav2 fl" title="Home" href="../A.html">      <!-- float:Left -->
    <span class="ico icoHome fl vm"></span> <!--float:left, problem : how to align middle vertically-->
    Test
  </a>
  <a class="BNav2 fl" title="Previous" href="../B.html">  <!-- float:left -->
    <span class="ico icoPrev fl vm"></span> <!--float:left, problem : how to align middle vertically-->
    Previous
  </a>
  <a class="BNav2 fr" title="Next" href="../C.html">      <!-- float:right -->
    <span class="ico icoNext fl vm"></span> <!--float:left, problem : how to align middle vertically-->
    Next
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `display: table` on the body and put everything in a container:

[Your Fiddle updated here](https://jsfiddle.net/ccftgzrz/)

**CSS**

```
body {          /* <-- you could use a div instead of body if you want */
    position:absolute; 
    display: table;    
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    ...
}

#container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
         All your vertically aligned content here
    </div>
</body>
```